# How to make scatter points a different shade based on group

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, linear-regression, scatter-plot

I am struggling with ggplot code. I have 7 lizard families, each with 2-3 species each. I have managed to plot regressions of the families (inclusive of their species), but now I want to make the scatter points different shades of the main family regression colour to display the different species within each family.

This is the current plot I have, displaying the regressions of all 7 lizard families (inclusive of their species). The code used to get this was:

```
fig25<-ggplot(data=Data_Jody, aes(x=log10(SVL), y=log10(SA), colour = Family))+
  geom_point(data=Data_Jody, aes(x=log10(SVL), y=log10(SA), colour = Family), size = 4.5, alpha = 0.4) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = T, level = 0.95)+
  guides(shape = guide_legend(keywidth = 0, keyheight = 0)) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(size = 0.75, colour = "black"), text = element_text(size=20))+ ylab(expression(log[10]~SA~(cm^{"2"})))+xlab(expression(log[10]~SVL~(cm)))
fig25
```

[image]

but I need the scatterpoints of each species within a family to be a different shade of the fanily regression colour. How do I go about doing this?